# populating the array with the user input

Tags: java

i apologize i know this looks simple but i'm kinda new to coding. the goal of the program is to take inputs from the user starting at index 0 and then save the inputs into the array. i'm probably close to solving this but i need some help.

here is the code:

```
public class ArrayTest
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numberOfGrades;
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("This program averages the grades you input.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of grades you'd like averaged: ");
    numberOfGrades = input.nextInt();

    int[] grades = new int[numberOfGrades];

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter grade number " + (counter+1) + ": ");
        grades[numberOfGrades] = input.nextInt();
        counter++;
    } while (counter < numberOfGrades);

    System.out.println("The number of grades you wanted averaged was: " + grades.length);


}
}
```

Comment: There is a typo, try `grades[counter] = input.nextInt();`

Comment: Does your code work? Does it error? Does it give the wrong output? What is the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: grades[counter] = input.nextInt(); there u went wrong...

Comment: Please describe how the code fails to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off. `numberOfGrades` is the.. well.. number of grades. And when you do this: `grades[numberOfGrades] = input.nextInt();` then you put the user's input in the `grades` array in location `numberOfGrades`, which you don't want.

What you do want is:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter grade number " + (counter+1) + ": ");
    grades[counter] = input.nextInt();
    counter++;
} while (counter < numberOfGrades);
```

This way, the array in location `counter` is accessed, and the user's input is placed inside it in the correct location.

Also, to calculate the average of the grades, like you are trying to do in the end of your program, you should do:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int grade : grades) 
    sum += grade;
```

And then your average will be:

```
average = 1.0d * sum / grades.length;
```

You can just as well put this summing logic inside your `do-while` loop and avoid the extra loop I introduced.

Answer (score 0):

this instruction

```
grades[numberOfGrades] = input.nextInt();
```

must be replaced by

```
grades[counter] = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

The thing that you were doing wrong is in the do while loop you were inserting value in the same array index `grades[numberOfGrades] = input.nextInt();`  should be replaced by `grades[counter] = input.nextInt();`

```
public class ArrayTest
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numberOfGrades;
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("This program averages the grades you input.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of grades you'd like averaged: ");
    numberOfGrades = input.nextInt();

    int[] grades = new int[numberOfGrades];

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter grade number " + (counter+1) + ": ");
        grades[counter] = input.nextInt();
        counter++;
    } while (counter < numberOfGrades);

    System.out.println("The number of grades you wanted averaged was: " + grades.length);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
  public class ArrayTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter number of elements");

int n=input.nextInt();

int arr[]=new int[n];

System.out.println("enter elements");

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for reading array
    arr[i]=input.nextInt();

}

for(int i: arr){ //for printing array

    System.out.println(i);

}
```

}